Book that tells the story of how a dragon was banished
A dragon wakes up in a cave with no memory of how long she'd been there or how she'd got there, one specific thing being she was too big for the cave, but when she left the cave she encountered two elves trying to save their species by saving the last female. Also the elves have a gold orb of magic powers.
After this at some point within three chapter she shapeshifts into a human, goes into town, meets the guy who took the female elf and becomes romantic with him only for him to betray her. She then vows not only to kill, but to never shape shift into a human again. This was after failing to save the elves, I think.

When did you read this?

If you remember more, you need to tell us about it. It's pointless (and counter-productive) to keep potentially useful information to yourself when you want us to locate this story for you.

Voting to close unless additional information is provided. Please don't play games with us.

More info would be appreciated but this does have enough info to be answerable. Please don’t use close votes as a super downvote
